# Will this implementation using TPL work inside a process running on an STA thread?

Tags: winforms, task-parallel-library

I want to create an instance of an object from an assembly  that implements an interface I define in my Forms app. I would create this object at app startup using `Activator.CreateInstance`, and keep an application-level reference to it.

At certain points during this application I want to call methods on this object without holding up the main thread using `Task.Run(() => IMyObject.DoSomeWork(someList, someList2))`. I just want to make a "fire and forget" void method call and I don't need to await or even register callbacks.

Will the fact that the app is running in an STA thread pose an issue? Do I have to worry about leaks or premature collection of objects I instantiate on the main thread and reference inside the task closure? I only intend to read the contents of these lists, not modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry; as soon as you create the delegate, all the objects it references will be kept in memory, at least until the `Task.Run` exits. There's nothing that an STA thread does that changes that.

Threads don't factor into GC at all - except that all stacks for running threads contain root objects. You can cross-reference objects however you want and it won't confuse the GC.

Comment: Thanks. So if I'm understanding correctly, even after the calling method exits, the delegate and referenced objects will still be around until the method called asynchronously completes?

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Yes. The delegate is passed to `Task.Run` and is still referenced by the thread pool when that method exits, even if it's not actually running yet.